# Android: How to draw another View in a custom-View's onDraw() method

Tags: android, user-interface, drawing

I need to create a custom view which is able to swipe between different views. I can't use ViewPager or the like, since it hasn't the transitions and features I need.

I started with this:

```
public final class DynamicSwipeView extends View {

    private View view;

    public DynamicSwipeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setPage(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        if (view != null) {
            view.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

But the other view (which works if used directly) isn't drawn. When I assign this swipe-view a background-color in the constructor, it's displayed in that color instead of white, but the other view isn't drawn nevertheless.

Comment: Did you also try `view.invalidate();`?  Please show your draw method.

Comment: I tried calling view.invalidate(); in the onDraw method. No changes. But onDraw is called correctly (I removed the logging-statements).

Comment: I don't have a draw() method in the other view.

Comment: there are other methods you need to redirect (what you are using here looks like a decorator pattern), mainly those related to being invalidated and measurement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a version I'm using written in Kotlin and it works nicely, tested on API 19, 25, and 28.

I'm using it for a floating header row for a `TableLayout` that I want anchored to the top of the screen. I assign `viewToDraw` in an `ViewTreeObserver.onGlobalLayoutListener` so I know the header row is laid out. This was convenient for me as I was listening to the view tree anyway, but this could be brought into the `CopyView` to `invalidate()` when necessary. The items in the header row and the `CopyView` are set to a fixed height, but you could expand on this to copy view dimensions too.

```
class CopyView @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    var viewToDraw: View? = null
        set(value) {
            field = value
            background = value?.background
            invalidate()
        }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        viewToDraw?.draw(canvas)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public final class DynamicSwipeView extends View {

    private View view;

    public DynamicSwipeView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public void setPage(View view) {
        this.view = view;
        this.invalidate();
    }


    @Override
    protected void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        if (view != null) {
            view.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

this is just a suggestion, I haven't tried it.

If it doesn't work, you should use a list of view and manage visibility of these views (current view = VISIBLE, others GONE). It could be easier to do like that.

Comment: I tried the .invalidate(), didn't help. Calling super.draw apparently calls onDraw(), thus it gives me a StackOverflowError.

Comment: I want to be able to be able to swipe and move the views around with my fingers, also animate them, so I don't see how Visibility helps me there. Thanks for your effort though!

Comment: consider you have a linearlayout in which you put your views. So you can add all your views in this linearlayout and set their visibility to GONE. And to show a view set its visibility to VISIBLE. Other possibility, instead of using visbility, you can just add the new view in the linearlayout and remove the old one. Do you see what I mean?

Comment: Yeah, but I want to be able to drag one view from the side so it covers the other and back. I don't see how to do that with linear-layout.